# Highchart is not define error while deploying on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, gruntjs, highcharts-ng

My project is in angualr js which is  working in my local with highcharts fine  but when I tried to deploy on the server it is giving error highhcarts is not define . whne i searched on the internet i found there is problem with grunt.js which is minify the js so does any one have idea how to get rid of that error (highchart is not define!!! )

Comment: Did you upload the JavaScript files? Do you see the source for highCharts? This is impossible for us to debug.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply . can you tell me which javascript files!

Comment: The one that contains the code for highcharts. Did you look at the developer console and see if you have 404s?

Comment: yes i saw developer console it is not giving me 404 .

Comment: So you did not upload the files

Comment: when i deploy on server in configuration file it is doing bower install which is getting all the dependencies

Comment: Well something is not right there.... Look at what the include paths are and look what the server has in that location.

Comment: what is in local that what going on server . i have double checked it that on server path for libraries are correct

Answer (score 0):

Either you have included the highcharts script twice, or you haven't included the highcharts script at all.

When using highcharts-ng you need to include these:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../../src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/cp73s/) of using "highvcharts-ng". Click on "ExternalResources" to see what scripts are loaded.

Comment: As my application is in angular i am using highcharts -ng and script is like this                                                                                                      <script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>               <script src="bower_components/highstock-release/highcharts-more.src.js"></script>                                                                            <script src="bower_components/highstock-release/highstock.src.js"></script>

Comment: thats what i am using in script to get highcharts and highstock libraries

Comment: so you mean i need to include only  <script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script> and <script src="bower_components/highstock-release/highstock.src.js"></script>

Comment: Yep! I added a demo to the answer.

Comment: First load `highstock.src.js` then load `highcharts-more.src.js` and as the last one load `highcharts-ng.js`. The order is simply so wrong..

Comment: i took that list of scripts directly from their example. You may have a different issue.

Comment: I solved the problem as i knew problem was with grunt file. there was path  of highstock  which needed to be updated in grunt. i appreciate your help thanks to all